# Menu is not Center aligned

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi am working on a website that takes dynamic menu from database. My issue is that the menu is not Center aligned. It is just shown on the top left corner its hosting div. Following is the code:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/offerboxindialogo9.png" class="img img-responsive"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" class="mymenu" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                                        Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="white" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" 
                                        StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" 
                                        RenderingMode="List" Width="100%">
                                        <DataBindings>
                                            <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="Item" NavigateUrlField="url" TextField="Text" ValueField="Value" />
                                            <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SubItem" NavigateUrlField="url" TextField="Text" ValueField="Value" />
                                        </DataBindings>
                                        <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="purple" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" VerticalPadding="10px" ForeColor="purple" BackColor="White"/>
                                        <DynamicMenuStyle BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="#990000" ForeColor="purple" />
                                        <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                                        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="purple" ForeColor="White" CssClass="hoverstyle" />
                                        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" VerticalPadding="10px" />
                                        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                        </asp:Menu>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried everything from css including float:none, display:inline, the Center tag, vertical-align:middle, even tried to use the following that I got as an answer in one of the similar posts at stack overflow:

```
.mymenu>ul>li>a
{
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

also tried 
    .mymenu ul li a
    {
        line-height: 50px;
    }
and also tried
    .mymenu+ul+li a
    {
        line-height: 50px;
    }
but nothing worked perfect. The problem with the first out of these three tries is that it is affecting the drop down menu items also.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                    <img id="Image1" class="img img-responsive" src="images/offerboxindialogo9.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div class="mymenu" id="NavigationMenu">
<ul class="level1">
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" >Home</a></li><li><a class="level1">Shopping</a><ul class="level2">
        <li><a class="level2">Electronics</a><ul class="level3">
        </ul></li><li><a class="level2">MEN</a><ul class="level3">
            <li><a class="level3" href="#" >Mobile & Tablets</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Computer & Laptop</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Mobile & Computer Accessories</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >TVs & Camera</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >TVs & Camera Accessories</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Wearables</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Network Components</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Home Entertainment</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Air Conditioners</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Refrigerators</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Washing Machine</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Kitchen Appliances</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Small Home Appliances</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >More</a></li>
            <li><a class="level3" href="#" >Footwear</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Clothing</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Watches</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Accessories</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Personal Care Appliances</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Grooming</a></li><li><a class="level3" href="#" >Featured</a></li>
        </ul></li><li><a class="level2">WOMEN</a><ul class="level3">
            <li><a class="level3" href="#" >Clothing1</a></li>
        </ul></li><li><a class="level2" href="#" >BABY & KIDS</a></li>
    </ul></li><li><a class="level1" href="#" >Festive Offers</a></li>
</ul>
</div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
```

Comment: You need to show the generated html and css that shows the problem. Also cause most people won't be able to help you with asp.net code.

Comment: Hi. as required, I have added the rendered HTML in description.